# Element is no longer valid

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Всем привет. Ребята, сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с такой проблемой? :

- получаю список вебэлементов по xpath -

  ```
  webdriver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr[contains(@id,'RadGrid1')]"))
  ```
- получаю первый элемент

  ```
  findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr[contains(@id,'RadGrid1')]")).get(0)
  ```
- получаю значение атрибута(например `id`)

  ```
  findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr[contains(@id,'RadGrid1')]")).get(0).getAttribute("id")
  ```

Все хорошо, но ...

- Если я создаю переменную типа `List<WebElement> listRecords` и
  присваиваю ей данный список

  ```
  List<WebElement> listRecords = webdriver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr[contains(@id,'RadGrid1')]"))
  ```
- обращаюсь к первому элементу - `listRecords.get(0)`
- хочу получить значение атрибута -
  `listRecords.get(0).getAttribute("id")`
- и получаю ошибку:

  > org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer valid (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

  якобы элемент устарел...

Подскажите, почему?

Comment: JavaScript какой нибудь?

Comment: Да, его очень много там...

Comment: Перед поиском этих элементов, сделайте слип просто на 3 секунды, если это решит проблему - то это точно какой то JS, который меняет просто DOM. Если таймоут не проблемма, то можно пользоваться таким решением (хоть оно и не очень надежно). Надежное решение - менять скрипт, что бы он вам сообщал явно, когда он закончил обновлять страницу.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. буду что-нибудь пробовать

Comment: @Webaib Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Часто виной тому является JavaScript, который начинает менять страницу, после того, как она полностью загружена.

Что бы проверить это, можно с помощью `Thread.sleep();` приостановить выполнение теста и если это решит проблему - то это 99% какой то JS.

1. Если `sleep()` не проблемма, то можно использовать такое решение. Оно, правда, не очень надежно и если таких слипов много, то удлиняет тесты.
2. Надежное решение - менять JS скрипт так, что бы он вам сообщал явно, когда он закончил обновлять страницу.